# Very Low Accuracy upon Retraining VGG16 in Keras

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I am trying to retrain VGG16 for a new dataset by using transfer learning. I have loaded the model with ImageNet weights and without the top fully connected layers, obtained predictions on the dataset from the bottleneck layers, and trained a small model with those bottleneck predictions. However, the validation accuracy is very low at 0.002 after 50 epochs. I am unable to figure out where the problem lies in my code, which is a modified version of the InceptionV3 retraining code from the Keras docs. I have been able to retrain ResNet50 on the same dataset with an accuracy of 0.88. My code is as below.

```python
from keras.applications import VGG16
from keras.preprocessing import image
from keras.models import Model
from keras.layers import Dense, Flatten, Dropout
from keras import backend as K
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from keras.layers import Input

img_width, img_height = 224, 224

train_data_dir = 'Dataset/train'
validation_data_dir = 'Dataset/test'

nb_train_samples = 31119
nb_validation_samples = 13362
nb_epoch = 50
nb_classes = 281
batch_size = 16

input_tensor = Input(shape=(224, 224, 3))
base_model = VGG16(weights="imagenet", input_tensor=input_tensor, include_top=False)

x = base_model.output
x = Flatten()(x)
x = Dense(256, activation='relu')(x)
x = Dropout(0.5)(x)
predictions = Dense(nb_classes, activation='sigmoid')(x)

model = Model(input=base_model.input, output=predictions)

for layer in base_model.layers:
    layer.trainable = False

model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop', loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=    ['accuracy'])

train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
        rescale=1./255)
test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)

train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    train_data_dir,
    target_size=(img_width, img_height),
    batch_size=16,
    class_mode='categorical'
)

validation_generator = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    validation_data_dir,
    target_size=(img_width, img_height),
    batch_size=16,
    class_mode='categorical'
)

history = model.fit_generator(
    train_generator,
    nb_epoch=nb_epoch,
    steps_per_epoch=nb_train_samples/batch_size,
    validation_data=validation_generator,
    validation_steps=nb_validation_samples/batch_size)
```

Comment: We usually go for the `softmax` activation at the end when using `categorical_crossentropy`. Any specific reason to use a `sigmoid`? Also, just a couple of comments: you don't need to set `steps_per_epoch` and `validation_steps` if you want all samples to be used; `target_size` should always be a `(height, width)` tuple. You reversed its members.

Answer (score 0):

VGG16 uses the Sequential model from Keras, ResNet the functional API.
Therefore, you should replace

```
x = base_model.output
x = Flatten()(x)
x = Dense(256, activation='relu')(x)
x = Dropout(0.5)(x)
predictions = Dense(nb_classes, activation='sigmoid')(x)

model = Model(input=base_model.input, output=predictions)
```

by

```
model = Models.Sequential()
model.add(base_model)
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(256, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(nb_classes, activation="softmax"))
```

Also use softmax instead of sigmoid when using categorical class_mode.